# Accessing Ruby Cucumber Module variables from inside and outside?

Tags: ruby, variables, scope, cucumber, gherkin

I have a Ruby Module that I want to use as a helper class for Cucumber step definitions.  I want the Module to contain a class variable that can be accessed from outside (the step definitions) as well as inside (a method within the module).  Here is a simplified version of my module:

```
module CalendarHelper
    def self.calendar_ids
        ids = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
    end

    def self.fillCalendarFields (browser)
        calendar_ids.each { |id|
            browser.text_field(:id => id).set '2001-01-01'
        }
    end
end
```

Here, the `fillCalendarFields` method needs to be able to access the `calendar_ids` class variable.

This is something I want to accomplish with my step definitions:

```
And /^the calendar fields are filled$/ do
    CalendarHelper.fillCalendarFields(@browser)
end


Then /^the calendar fields are cleared$/ do
    CalendarHelper.calendar_ids.each { |id|
        @browser.text_field(:id => id).set ""
    }
end
```

The first step definition calls the `fillCalendarFields` method from the module.  The second step definition accesses the `calendar_ids` variable for its own use.  Any advice on how to properly do this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
World(CalendarHelper)
```

Should do the trick. Though you'll no longer need to call them via "CalendarHelper". What this code will do is extend World with the methods you have in there.

Comment: Thank you!  This really helped.  I guess I was just missing that little part.